# Why does debugger keep telling me that ) is missing? Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, debugging

I'm trying to make my way through a tutorial that will teach me how to make Javascript APIs for arcgis, but I'm having more problems than I should getting this code to execute so. This is the current tutorial I'm on:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_agstemplate_amd.html

and this is the error I get when I check for errors in the console:

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

here is my code:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<head>
<title> Create a Web Map</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content"text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Campatible" content="IE=edge">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.14/esri/css/esri.css">
<style>
    html,body,#mapDiv,.map.container{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    }
</style>

<script> var dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad:true};</script>
<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.14compact/"></script>
<script>
    var map;
    require(["esri/map",
    "esri/arcgis/utils",
    "dojo/domReady!"
    ],function(Map,arcgisUtils){
    arcgisUtils.createMap(2756c157f67d435c871bc816abb1267c,"mapDiv").then(function (response) {
        map = response.map;
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mapDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This all looks right enough to me.
I don't understand how to get around this error. From what I can tell all of my parenthetical statements are closed. Last time I wrote this code I got a different error message about response.
Can someone point out the solution to this error in my code?
Can anyone offer advice on how to do this better?
Does anyone know of any better resources to use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't put a string in string literals, so the compiler is confused.

Wrap 2756c157f67d435c871bc816abb1267c like `"2756c157f67d435c871bc816abb1267c"` and the code correctly parses in Inspect Element.

Comment: No, count again, his require is closed by the last ')'

Comment: my text editor says that the ) is closed on line 28.

Comment: check the other answer. I put some more errors I don't understand there in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually missing quotes. this:

```
arcgisUtils.createMap(2756c157f67d435c871bc816abb1267c, "mapDiv")
```

Should be this:

```
arcgisUtils.createMap("2756c157f67d435c871bc816abb1267c", "mapDiv")
```

Comment: init.js:152 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/2756c157f67d435c871bc816abb1267c?f=json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: init.js:182 q {message: "Unable to load file://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/…2756c157f67d435c871bc816abb1267c?f=json status: 0", response: Object, status: 0, responseText: "", xhr: XMLHttpRequest…}